# Sharing config among multiple applications in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create multiple application under 1 codeigniter application, however some of them would be sharing same config such as database config.

```
-application
  -config
  -models
  -project_1
    -config
    -controllers
    -models
  -project_2
    -config
    -controllers
```

is it possible to load the config in the first level of application folder, and look for the application level's folder if the config file doesn't exist? I know it is possible when I load configs manually by using add_package_path(), but autoload doesn't work.

Comment: Have you thought aboutlooked at Environments?
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/environments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use packages:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

I tend to create a package called 'share' within the web root, i.e. packages/share

Inside your packages folder, you can create a folder structure similar that of the core CI application config, helpers, models, views etc.

Say you want to only have one DB file, you can place the db config file inside packages/share/config and call this file using the following within your applications database file:

```
include_once(FCPATH . 'packages/share/config/database.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep it simple:

```
<?php

    // This app has no config. Use the shared one
    require_once('/path/to/common/config.php');
```